# 「スペクトラルノイズ除去による雑音除去」によるNameErrorメッセージ

Tags: python, python3

スペクトラルノイズ除去による雑音除去
https://www.ai-shift.co.jp/techblog/1305

上記サイトを見て、Jupyter Notebookでノイズ除去を実行したいのですが、
二つ目のプログラムの12行目にある以下の部分でエラーメッセージが出ます。

> ```
> noise_stft = _stft(noise_clip, n_fft, hop_length, win_length)
> ```

**エラー:**

```
NameError:name'noise_clip' is not defined
```

サイトのどの部分を見ても `noise_clip` はその12行目だけにしかないです。
解決方法分かればお願いします。

Comment: 検索して名前と分野的にもしかしたら関係するかも？ という記事がこちら。[How to find noise point of .wav file. i mean, not remove noise, just when occurred noise by using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62949384/9014308), [Methods for sound noise reduction](https://www.kaggle.com/mauriciofigueiredo/methods-for-sound-noise-reduction), [1.0-test-noise-reduction.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/timsainb/noisereduce/blob/master/notebooks/1.0-test-noise-reduction.ipynb), [librosa.stft](http://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html) `y : np.ndarray [shape=(n,)], real-valued    input signal`

Comment: 既に解決済みですね。 [「スペクトラルノイズ除去による雑音除去」によるNameErrorメッセージ｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/362175)

Answer (score 0):

参照先記事
[スペクトラルノイズ除去による雑音除去](https://www.ai-shift.co.jp/techblog/1305)
呼び出すライブラリ・メソッドの情報
[librosa.stft](http://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html)

> Parameters : y : np.ndarray [shape=(n,)], real-valued
> 　　　　　　　　input signal

上記記事より、`noise_clip`が渡されるのは`librosa.stft()`というライブラリ・メソッドで`y`パラメータ(numpy配列の`入力信号`)ですね。

そして、以下のあたりの記事で、`入力信号`は`.wav`等の波形データであり、`librosa`ライブラリだと`load`メソッドで`.wav`ファイル等を読み取ったものか、numpy等で作り出したものと考えられます。
[信号処理とか音楽の分析に大活躍しそうなlibrosa](https://qiita.com/tom_m_m/items/91ba624dd8507bc0b746)
[Pythonの音声処理ライブラリ【LibROSA】で音声読み込み⇒スペクトログラム変換・表示⇒位相推定して音声復元](https://qiita.com/lilacs/items/a331a8933ec135f63ab1)
[Methods for sound noise reduction](https://www.kaggle.com/mauriciofigueiredo/methods-for-sound-noise-reduction)
[librosa.load](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.load.html)

参照先記事によると`noise_clip`の他に同様に`audio_clip`というものも必要なので、名前からして参照先記事の「ノイズ部分の特定」の説明から類推すると`audio_clip`が「元音源」データで、`noise_clip`がSound Envelopで処理された「元音源のノイズ部分」データと思われます。

おそらく「元音源」は参照先記事の最初に掲載されている12秒間の音声データで、「元音源のノイズ部分」は3つ目に掲載されている10秒間の音声データのことでしょう。

なので記事からそれぞれのデータを`.wav`ファイルとしてダウンロードして、質問で問題としている行よりも前に以下のようにデータを読み取っておけば良いと思われます。

```
import librosa
audio_clip, rate = librosa.load('元音源.wav')
noise_clip, rate = librosa.load('元音源のノイズ部分.wav')

import scipy.signal #### 上記と直接は関係無いが参照先記事の後で必要になるもの
```

処理結果が正しいかどうかは別にして、参照先記事の各ソースをつなぎ合わせて、上記部分を適当な位置に挿入すれば、エラー無しに実行出来るようになります。

---

あるいは、`audio_clip`を参照先記事の最初のソース`envelope()`で処理した結果が`noise_clip`となるのかもしれません。
例えば以下のように：

```
audio_clip, rate = librosa.load('元音源.wav')
noise_mask, noise_clip = envelope(audio_clip, rate, 何かの雑音判断するしきい値)

#### 更にこの後何かの処理が必要になるのかもしれませんが。
```

Comment: audio_clip, rate = librosa.load('元音源.wav')　　このやり方で今のところ問題なく動いてるように見えます！ありがとうございます。